# what happens when we change the value which is in loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

my question is what happens when we change `j=i+1` to `j = 0` or 
`j = i`. I mean what is the difference between the two cases?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindNearestPoints {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of points: ");
    int numberOfPoints = input.nextInt();

    // Create an array to store points
    double[][] points = new double[numberOfPoints][2];
    System.out.print("Enter " + numberOfPoints + " points: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      points[i][0] = input.nextDouble();
      points[i][1] = input.nextDouble();
    }

    // p1 and p2 are the indices in the points array
    int p1 = 0, p2 = 1; // Initial two points
    double shortestDistance = distance(points[p1][0], points[p1][1], 
      points[p2][0], points[p2][1]); // Initialize shortestDistance

    // Compute distance for every two points
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
        double distance = distance(points[i][0], points[i][1],
          points[j][0], points[j][1]); // Find distance

        if (shortestDistance > distance) {
          p1 = i; // Update p1
          p2 = j; // Update p2
          shortestDistance = distance; // Update shortestDistance 
        }
      }
    }

    // Display result
    System.out.println("The closest two points are " +
      "(" + points[p1][0] + ", " + points[p1][1] + ") and (" +
      points[p2][0] + ", " + points[p2][1] + ")");
  }

  /** Compute the distance between two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)*/
  public static double distance(
      double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] *in the question* - along with what you've already observed when trying this for yourself.

Comment: Obviously, the second loop then starts running from either 0 or 1 instead of from `i+1`, and in both cases you will have the situation that j=i, so you are trying to find the distance between `points[i]` and `points[i]`. So, that will be zero, so your shortestDistance will always be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `j = i` then the minimum distance would be zero since you'd be computing the distance between a point with itself!

If you set `j = 0` the above would still apply, albeit with unnecessary duplicated comprisons, since you'd be including `j == i`.

Answer (score -1):

when we change `j=i+1` to `j = 0` or `j = i`

The First time we get to the `for statement` in you code, a variable j will be made and initialized to `i+1`.

Changing it to any other value,we will get different initialization value.